# Problem with memory deallocation for non-dynamically created std::vectors storing normal (i.e. non-dynamically allocated) data

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, std

Consider the following code, compiled with `g++ problem.cpp -o problem`:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

When this code is executed, the command `top` reports that ~80K of memory is being consumed.

Now consider this code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> testVec;
    for(int i = 0;i<100000000;i++)testVec.push_back(i);
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, top report that around ~300MB of memory is consumed.

Now finally, consider this code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> testVec;
    for(int i = 0;i<100000000;i++)testVec.push_back(i);
    testVec.clear();
    vector<int>().swap(testVec);
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

Now `top` reports that ~4196K is being consumed(!) -- why isn't it only ~80K is as in the first example? How can I finally free up that last bit of memory that is presumably being consumed by the vector? I've read that in addition to `.clear()`, the 'swap trick' is meant to free up everything but apparently it's not working as I expected it would do. What am I missing?

Comment: Vectors dynamically-allocate their data. How could they not?

Comment: ...in the underlying implementation. I see now that perhaps my problem statement is indeed naive, but still the mind boggles..

Comment: By the question's very nature you're talking about the lowest-level details of the underlying implementation. How can you simultaneously pretend to abstract them away?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably just ignore it. The `swap` trick frees the memory from the vector, but that does not mean that the allocator (or even the `malloc` or equivalent implementation underneath) will yield the memory back to the system. That is, the vector is most probably not the one holding the memory up.

Comment: +1: Correct. The OP is trying to formulate predictions about the behaviour of his process's memory usage, with absolutely no axioms to go on whatsoever other than a relatively arbitrary and naive code comparison to an empty program.

Comment: Hmmm...it just seems damn bizarre that this sort of thing can happen. I mean, the memory gets used because of the allocation and then I attempt to de-allocate it in the only way possible(?). So I guess my question now becomes: how can one ensure that the allocator will yield the memory back to the system? (Do I even have control over this?)

Comment: @Ben: No. This is something you should neither worry nor care about.

Comment: @Ben You cannot control that. In most cases it will not even be the C++ allocator, but the implementation of `malloc`, and they are tailored to perform that way because it makes the most sense in most of the situations. Very smart people working on operating systems have implemented those strategies into the allocators (system level `malloc`, not C++ allocator) because they provide the *right* balance of memory usage/performance. There might be a couple of things that you can do to minimize the effect, as for example calling `reserve` to minimize the memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there are two ways to deallocate memory on this case:

1. Put the code that use vector in bracket (simple and efficient)

   ```
   {
      // ..........
   }
   ```
2. Use shared pointer, but make sure that there is exactly only one shared pointer. You can call "reset" in order to free up the memory.

   ```
   shared_ptr<vector<int> > testVec(new vector<int>);
   ```

Comment: -1: Sorry, but you completely missed the point, and these approaches are (more or less) functionally equivalent to the OP's program. Meanwhile, why would you ever use `shared_ptr` if you're going to mandate that you don't share it?